# Iterate through multiple columns of dataframe that contain the same substring

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following Data Frame:

| Index | foo | String A | bar | String B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 15 | nan | 0 | 3 |
| Second | 0 | 2 | 25 | nan |

I have the following logic that allows me to iterate through a single column of a data frame and access a specific cell and change its value. If the value of the cell in the column with the name `String A` is NOT `NaN` then the value of the cell in the column that comes before it should be changed to `NaN`

```
for idx, val in enumerate(df['String A']):
        if not math.isnan(val) :
            df.iloc[: , df.columns.get_loc('String A')-1].iloc[idx] = np.nan
```

Is there a way I could generalize the loop so I could iterate through all columns that contain the substring `String` such that the loop applies for both columns `String A` and `String B` (or any column that contains this substring).

The table should then look like this:

| Index | foo | String A | bar | String B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 15 | nan | nan | 3 |
| Second | nan | 2 | 25 | nan |

**Edit**: Added more details to the question

Comment: So if "String A" is not `NaN`, you change the value from the same row in "Col A"? Similarly, "String B" would change the value in "Col B"?

Comment: @not_speshal Exactly. If "String A" is not `NaN` I can change the value of the column that comes before that column and so on for every column with the substring "String"

Comment: What do you change the value to? Can you post an actual example with dummy values instead of "row" "row"? And also your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for idx in [i for i, c in enumerate(df.columns) if c.startswith("String")]:
    df.iloc[:, idx-1] = df.iloc[:, idx-1].where(df.iloc[:,idx].isnull())

>>> df
         foo  String A   bar  String B
Index                                 
First   15.0       NaN   NaN       3.0
Second   NaN       2.0  25.0       NaN
```

Comment: Sorry for not making the table elaborate enough. I didn't know the name `Col A` or `Col B` was relevant. The names of these columns could be any kind of string so (for example <foo>, <bar>) so `lstrip` won't work

Comment: That's why I specifically asked if String A modifies Col A and String B modifies Col B. To which you answered yes.

Comment: You never asked me if those were the actual names of the columns. But the pattern for `String A` still holds. `Col A` or `Col B` however could be any random string

Comment: @DanG - I did specify *"String B" would change the value in "Col B"*. Either way, edited the answer.

Comment: This code does what I need it to, but I don't understand one part of it. Isn't `.where(df.iloc[:,idx].isnull())` supposed to tell it to make the cell of the previous column `NaN` if the cell of the current column is `NaN` ? It does however make the cell of the previous column `NaN` if the cell of the current column is **NOT** `NaN`

**Update**: Nevermind, if weren't lazy and read the documentation I would've gotten my answer

Comment: `df.iloc[:, idx-1].where(df.iloc[:,idx].isnull())` simply means: if column idx has null values, return the corresponding values from idx-1 (otherwise it defaults to null). Look at the documentation for [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain use of your original for loop you could do the following:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(df): 
    if 'String' in val: 
        print(val)
```